# Booting from usb just goes back to bios menu

Tags: boot, usb

I have gone through the process of installing the boot for usb drive. The drive had no problems when I went through the process. The problem is when I try to boot from the drive it just goes to the windows boot up.

So I tried disabling the windows drive and only allowing the usb and then what happen was it just keeps going back to the bios menu like there is nothing there.

I am using windows 10 Home 32-bit installed by manufacture, on an asus netbook model `X205TA`. I tried installing ubuntu 17.04 through the set up that ubuntu provides to put on a usb drive.

Comment: did you change the boot order to put USB before the internal HDD? NOTE: some systems do not support USB boot

Comment: Please tell us about the computer: Brand name and model. Tell us also which Windows version there is, and if it was installed by the manufacturer/vendor. Finally, please tell us which version of Ubuntu you are trying to install and how you installed it into the USB drive (which tool you used).

Comment: @sudodus added in the edit

Comment: I just used the tutorial they have on how to put on a usb drive. Sorry I am not tech smart when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: I have this device. It's a bootloader issue - you need a 64-bit iso image and you need to [add bootia32.efi to the USB after writing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498) , or on a Linux system (**highly advisable**) use [this script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25740598/) (download as text) to repackage the iso before [writing it to the USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781223/781236#781236) (`chmod u+x <scriptname>` then `sudo ./<scriptname> <name_of_iso_file>.iso`) To get sound after installation you'll have to use a patched kernel (should be merged in 4.13 though)

Comment: @Zanna, make an answer from this comment :-)

Comment: @sudodus ok, I am doing it...

Comment: @Zanna, would you have time to test if the compressed image file from the following link would work in ASUS X205TA?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent/LXLE -- I have found that it works in many different computers, 32-bit, 64-bit, BIOS, UEFI, even secure boot.

Comment: @sudodus I am testing the latest version of harryharryharry's script. The device has a WontFix bug that breaks wifi and numerous other problems. See [the 182 page thread about it on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254322) However I will test your image after testing the one I'm doing now :)

Comment: @Zanna I am trying your method now

Comment: @Zanna it worked! Now I just need to figure how to connect to wifi ='(

Comment: yeah that's why I suggest the script. The wifi issue is a WontFix Debian bug. However [here's the fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768036/connection-to-wifi-network-with-my-asus-x205ta/768194#768194)

Comment: @Zanna I got the wifi to work, but now I am facing a problem with having to run the `sudo modprobe brcmfmac` command in the terminal every time I restart =/

Comment: hmm I should probably update that answer... I am hoping to write an answer for you, but I'm finding it stressful because there are so many issues and the state of support is a constantly moving target. If I do manage, it will probably be based on [this forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254322&page=178&p=13681047#post13681047)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67143/discussion-between-taylor-austin-and-zanna).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if @Zanna is going to post the answer but all I needed to do is add a file to the boot drive and make sure secure boot was off.

Here is the file [Ubuntu on 32-bit UEFI (only) based tablet pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498/ubuntu-on-32-bit-uefi-only-based-tablet-pc)

Comment: It works well! Now I just need help on making the wifi work =( I wish this was as easy as install and go

Comment: Thanks for sharing your result and good luck with the wifi :-)