# ASUS X205TA WiFi on Ubuntu Budgie 19.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus, ubuntu-budgie

I just installed Ubuntu Budgie on this little laptop and everything works flawlessly EXCEPT wifi.

It was an issue in Windows 10 too, which is what prompted me to try Linux on this thing.

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/768194/976231) answer but the nvram thingy in efivars isn't there (there isnt a single nvram thing in there) and copying the command gives in fact `cp: cannot stat '/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-43268123d113': No such file or directory` as a result.

How do I get the txt file I need to make this work? Do I have an alternative to this to make the internal card work? with this distro? I don't want to use an external one because the ports on this laptop are a bit flimsy and for some reason the slightest little bump makes it disconnect and reconnect.

Thanks.

EDIT: I should mention that I don't care about bluetooth not working

EDIT2: [This](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wYtmTgkJ8K/) is the file that I got from the script suggested by @Rinzwind (updated to pastebin).

Comment: I would have asked about the wifi related problem ;) Please do provide the information about your system with the script explained here https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/15811  It will list all needed information for resident wifi expert @chili555 to help you. All we  then need is for him to show up >:)

Comment: I ran it without the WiFi USB card, is that ok? Also, where do I put the .tar.gz? Should I put it as an answer?

Comment: In the link chili555 said to use pastebin but that works too ;) now how to get chili here :)

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode?

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes it is.

Comment: See Step 2 @ https://askubuntu.com/a/768194/300665

Comment: As I already said, the nvram things are not present in efivars.

Comment: I'm progressively starting to think this may be a hardware issue :\

Comment: What happens when you `mount -t efivars efivars /sys/firmware/efi/efivars`  Can you then find /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Comment: sorry for replying so late, I get `mount: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars: unknown filesystem type 'efivars'.` after putting this command

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded [this](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt) to `/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt`

Then I run

```
sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac && sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

It worked right after this command, but it might need reboot